In the Athanasian Creed, is the Son part of the Father?
In the Athanasian Creed, the three Persons are one God, and the ‘one God’ is the Trinity. The question is, how are the three Persons one God?
If Father = Son = Spirit, that would be Modalism, where the Father, Son, and Spirit are three names for the same one Entity. So, I want to assume that Father, Son, and Spirit are not simply three names for the same Entity, but that there are differences between them.
The Creed also says that the three Persons differ. For example, the Father begat the Son. So, while the Father has a Son, the Son does not have a Son. Such differences exclude Modalism.
The following suggest that the Son and Spirit are part of the Father:

Firstly. the Creed says they are one undivided substance. (“nor dividing the Substance"). It also says that the Father is the Source and Origin of the Son and the Spirit. The ‘undivided substance’, therefore, is the substance of the Father. With the Son begotten and the Spirit proceeding, that Substance remains undivided. This means that the Son and Spirit are part of the Father’s Substance; the Son is part of the Father.

Secondly, that is also what Athanasius taught:




“In the Father we have the Son: this is a summary of Athanasius’ theology.” (Hanson, p. 426)
“The Son is in the Father ontologically.” (Hanson, p. 428)
“Athanasius’ increasing clarity in treating the Son as intrinsic to the Father’s being” (Ayres, p. 113)
“Athanasius’ argument speaks not of two realities engaged in a common activity, but develops his most basic sense that the Son is
intrinsic to the Father’s being.” (Ayres, p. 114) (Read More)


If the Athanasian Creed is supposed to reflect Athanasius’ theology, which I suspect it does, it would be fair to conclude that the Son and Spirit are part of the Father.

Thirdly, Athanasius was the norm of Western pro-Nicene theology and that theology relied heavily on Tertullian, who also said that the Son is part of the Father.


“The Father is the entire substance, but the Son is a derivation and
portion of the whole.” (In Against Praxeas 9, Tertullian)


Yet again, Athanasius is mentioned but not quoted, his words being misrepresented by others. Yet again an opinion is expressed without accurate consideration in regard to the true concept of the doctrine being attacked. And yet again, I down-vote a question lacking proper and responsible academic research.

Your statement that "The ‘undivided substance’, therefore, is the substance of the Father" is true but misleading, according to standard Trinitarian theology. The same undivided substance is also the substance of the Son and the substance of the Holy Spirit. The Nicene Creed describes the Son as consubstantial with the Father. There is one divine substance, undivided and common to all three divine Persons.

"the Athanasian Creed is supposed to reflect Athanasius’ theology" close but it's more likely Augustinian theology. Despite its common name, it is a Western creed, not an Eastern one. It's likely derived from Prosper of Aquitaine quoting Augustine's De Trinitate.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The main question is, "How are the three Persons one God?". Nobody is ever going to be able to tell you how, this side of heaven. The next question attempts to break into this humanly unanswerable question by asking, "Is the Son part of the Father?" Well, first, it would be vital to explain what is meant by "part of". The Trinity doctrine is clear that God cannot be divided into parts. Yet the Son cannot exist apart from the existence of the Father, any more than the Holy spirit can exist apart from the existence of the Father and the Son. This does not explain "how", either.
Yet examination of the way the doctrine emerged intact despite massive attempts to crush it helps to explain why this was so vital to the continuation of the Christian faith. Here is a telling quote from a scholar's chapter on Athanasius:

"Athanasius served as archbishop and patriarch of Alexandria for
forty-five years until his death in 373 [but note that the Athanasian Creed was
not until the late 5th century, reflecting various accrued theological
points]. He spent approximately one-third of that time in forced exile
due to his steadfast defense of the key terminology of the Nicene
Creed [325] in the face of imperial opposition. With good reason he
has come to be known as the 'saint of stubbornness' because of his
uncompromising opposition to anything that smacked of Arianism - even
when emperors threatened his life. It may not be much of an
exaggeration to say that all Christians have Athanasius to thank that
the theology of Jehovah's Witnesses is not the 'orthodoxy' of most of
Christendom.
...He was the greatest theologian of his time... Athanasius lived
defending his understanding of the Catholic faith, as declared at
Nicaea." The Story of Christian Theology, Roger E. Olson, pp.161-2 &
166, Inter-Varsity, 1999

To delve into his reasons for the way he described the relationship of the Son of God to the Father, one would need to learn about the synod which he called in Alexandria in 362. Bishops gathered to reaffirm homoousios as the only proper word to describe this. They explicitly rejected both the semi-Arian homoiousios and Sabellianism (modalism) as heresies. Now follows important points regarding the question as in the book previously quoted from:

"The synod took a new step that would be crucial in the success of the
Nicene doctrine of the Trinity at the Council of Constantinople in
381. Aided by his friends the Cappadocian fathers (Basil and the two Gregories), Athanasius proposed and the synod accepted an explanatory
statement that declared the Father, Son and Holy Spirit to be three
distinct but not separate hypostases of the one God. This absolutely
crucial conceptual leap can be understood only in the context of the
three Cappadocian fathers...
...hypostasis (of which hypostases is the plural) is a Greek word
that could either mean "individual subsistence" (like a person) or
else "common substance" (like human nature). In other words, it could
be synonymous with ousia (substance) or not. If not, it generally
meant the particular thing or individual example (subsistence) of a
common substance or species. This was clearly the intended meaning of
Athanasius's Alexandrian synod in 362.
The purpose of putting forth this new idea was to contradict Sabellian
modalism by making clear that Father, Son and Holy Spirit, though one
substance (homoousias), are not the same identical person or
substance. They are three distinct persons (hypostases) and not
merely three masks or manifestations or aspects of the one personal
God, as Sabellianism averred." (Ibid. p. 166)

These points should help direct further studies on this complex matter. They should also show that many other Christians were deeply involved in formulating the precise wording finally settled on, other than Athanasius. As he had many enemies both then and now, one would expect those who disagree strongly about the Trinity doctrine to try to fault him. But more often than not the fault lies with either misunderstanding what he meant, or not doing justice to setting forth the lines of his arguments. Nothing can be done about that except to try to keep the record straight by quoting from scholars who know their stuff, as I have given a hint of in this partial answer.

The question is not "How are the three Persons one God?" The question is how the AC (Athanasian Creed) describes them as one. And whether it describes the Son as part of the Father. To answer this question by saying what the Trinity doctrine or the Bible says is irrelevant. My question is about the AC.

@Andries  I merely quote your words, "The question is, how are the three Persons one God?" Creeds are not explanations of how something believed is so: they are statements of what is believed. If you think the AC alone is what needs to be examined, could you kindly start by quoting from it the relevant bits? Do flag up any bits where the Son is said to be "part of the Father." If it nowhere claims that the Son is part of the Father, then perhaps your question about that is invalid?

Context is king.
